# Can we see stars in day time by making use of a blue notch-filter?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, air

Given on a clear sunny day, the only light that is blocking the star light is the scattered blue light of atmosphere.

If we make use of a notch filter, which blocks only the blue light, can we get to see the stars? Will the sky turn black and give us a feel as if there is no atmosphere?!

Or is the atmospheric scattering spread across a wider spectrum that a filter to block the scattering light ends up blocking most of star light too?!

Comment: Considering that the sky is typically pale blue rather than a deep blue, I expect that all visible wavelengths are present and quite bright.  Biased towards the shorter wavelengths but not restricted to them.

Comment: [Worth reading?](http://adsbit.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1911PA.....19..162C&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES)

Comment: see this https://www.skysurfer.eu/daystars.php

Comment: A polarizing filter might also help.

Comment: @BenCrowell so, a filter and a polariser it is! The hunt begins for the duo!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the range of blue cone reception in frequncies, and then it is the biology of [color perception](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html) that takes over:

> [The graphic below](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/Visible-Light-and-the-Eye-s-Response) is a sensitivity curve that depicts the range of wavelengths and the sensitivity level for the three kinds of cones.

[image]

[image: colper]

T[he filter](http://midopt.com/filters/bp470/) you propose seems to cover (430-500nm)

That leaves a lot of blue sensitive perception free, so I would guess no, it would not work.

Here is the content that gives the  blue  of the sky in frequencies :

[image: blue sky]

> [A spectrum taken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_sky_radiation) of blue sky clearly shows solar Fraunhofer lines and the atmospheric water absorption band.

Nevertheless, if you have access to such a filter ,why don't you try, on a clear day? or put it on a camera and take a picture in daytime?

Comment: I wish to! If I get hands on some filter, I will! What will be the spectrum of the scattering from the atmosphere? Is it as continuous as sun’s?

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: The spectrum of blue sky peaks well below 500nm. The spectrum you show appears to be the spectrum of sunlight.